# $_SESSION getting overwritten instead of appended

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a some ajax in a wordpress plugin that does the following,

```
    function hamper_builder_add_product() {
    $product = wc_get_product($_POST['product_id']);
    $_SESSION['hamper_products'][] = $_POST['product_id'];
    die(print_r($_SESSION));
}
```

This gets fired when an add button is clicked and it should add the product id to the hamper_products array in the session, if a user clicks add for product 1, and then product 2 I would expect the response to look like this,

```
Array ( [hamper_products] => Array ( [0] => 1, [1] => 2 ) ),
```

however all that happens is the array has one index that gets overwritten, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the output that you get?

Comment: @B001ᛦ `Array ( [hamper_products] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) )` the value of [0] just gets overwritten.

Comment: Weird, I can't reproduce that :/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Wordpress doesn't use PHP's session, it is the core design decision. As far as I understand you are using WooCommerce, then better to leverage its functionality for sessions:

```php
$hamperProducts =  WC()->session->get('hamper_products');
$hamperProducts[] = $_POST['product_id'];
WC()->session->set('hamper_products', $hamperProducts);
```

After all if you want to use PHP's session for that, make sure to call `session_start` before usage.

Comment: You still would overwrite the session variable as you are overwriting `$hamperProducts`

Comment: @B001ᛦ can you show me the line where it ges overwritten?

Comment: `$hamperProducts[] = $_POST['product_id'];` At this time you define a new array and then  `WC()->session->set('hamper_products', $hamperProducts);`  you overwrite the session which is IMHO equivalent to `WC()->session->set('hamper_products', $_POST['product_id']);`

Comment: I am assuming `hamper_products ` is array from the beginning, and no `$hamperProducts[]` doesn't define new array, it appends new element to existing array.

Comment: My bad, I totally overlooked this line `WC()->session->get('hamper_products');` But still I'm unsure what happens the first time you call session->get() when there was nothing added before, I thik in this case `$hamperProducts ` would'nt be an array

Comment: @B001ᛦ okay, I give up :D do you know $_SESSION is a global variable tho?